# Redactor source plugin working on Text field but not on a Text field in Matrix

Tags: plugins, redactor

I'm on 2.6.2988, I have a text-block in my entry with standard Redactor settings enabled showing the source-button in the menu.

In the same entry I have a Matrix field with text-block with standard Redactor settings but the source-button is not showing.

Is Matrix using a different config?

Comment: Shouldn't be any difference inside or outside of Matrix?  Are they using the same Redactor config under the RTF settings?  Any JavaScript errors in your browser's console when you view the one inside of Matrix?

Comment: yes same settings, but the matrix field is missing source and fullscreen buttons, both are plugins in the config. Maybe plugins are disabled for the matrix redactor? There are no js-errors in the console.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this.  If I made sure both of the rich text fields have the Craft stock "Standard.json" config selected in the field's "Redactor Config" settings, then the source button shows up in both a standalone rich text field as well as one inside of Matrix. This is on a fresh Craft install.

Comment: ok it works, standard.json was not selected in matrix-text-block. In german settings you can select standard.json or standart (german word for default but than it uses simple.json) , I haven't seen that. thanks for you patience

Answer (score 1):

in german settings look carefully at the Redactor-Konfiguration , if you select Standardwert it uses Simple.json and not Standard.json.